# Irrlicht engine: code commenting convention?

Tags: c++, coding-style

I've recently been skimming through Irrlicht's 3D game engine source code, and I really like their commenting styles. For example, they use `/param` to specify function parameters, and `/intro` for introduction and so on.

After reading over dozen of files, I was wondering if this is self-created commenting style or some kind of standard coding style that be found in books?

thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think the comments are written in a style that is a syntax for a documentation generator, such as [doxygen](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/docblocks.html).

Comment: Yes, sometimes people do this even when they don't use a documentation generator, to have a uniform style.

Comment: @user385261, check out doxygen, it's really good. There are many others too.

Comment: It's a wonderful tool for people who think they can generate documentation without actually writing it. Then you end up with wonderful documentation which tells you that `setFoo(Foo)` is a function which sets the foo, and, that the `Foo` parameter is "the foo to set". Gotta love it.

Comment: @jalf: Why the hate? It is useful for documenting non-trivial code.

Comment: @BjörnPollex: is it? *Documentation* is useful for documenting non-trivial code. I just don't recall ever seeing Doxygen being used to produce *real* useful documentation. Sure, theoretically, there's nothing stopping you from writing actual documentation with it, but in practice, it is nearly always used to generate trivial and obvious factoids about the code which tell you nothing you didn't already know

Comment: @jalf: I think it is great for explaining the parameters, return values, and other minor aspects. However, explaining how-to and overall frameworks, in my opinion, must be done manually.

Comment: Therefore, I think I'll be using it to create a reference-like part of the documentation. The real thing should be handwritten explanation with examples.

Comment: @user: Take a look at the Ogre3d [API reference](http://www.ogre3d.org/docs/api/html/index.html). It's generated with doxygen. Since the engine's open source, you can skim through the source itself to see their comments.

Comment: @user385261: agreed. But the problem IMO is that (1) people tend to skip the second part (the handwritten explanation) once they have Doxygen, and (2), if your parameters and functions are properly named, those things shouldn't require much/any explanation at all. But as long as you remember the second part, that's the main thing. :)